# How to get my own Google Plus Page Followers Count?

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus

I know that API doesnt let you check any Google plus page followers count, I have hidden my followers count so it's not public (I cant scrap it).

Yes I wanna pull it every now and then to a data base, is there any authenticated way to pull only "my followers count"?

Thanks